# The nested type maintype cannot hide an enclosing type

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

Solved it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```